# Finding the maximum of a function on a specific interval

Tags: derivatives, optimization, roots, laplace-transform, maxima-minima

I have a problem at it is as follows. I've to find the maxium value of the following function between to time points, namely $t=0$ and $t=\frac{2}{50}$. The function is the following:

$$8-\exp(-\frac{2500t}{3})+(4\exp(-\frac{125(20t-1)}{3})-8)\cdot\theta(t-\frac{1}{20})$$

Where $\theta$ is the HeavisideTheta function.

I did the following analysis:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left\{8-\exp(-\frac{2500t}{3})+(4\exp(-\frac{125(20t-1)}{3})-8)\cdot\theta(t-\frac{1}{20})\right\}=0\rightarrow$$
$$t=$$

But that makes it realy hard. So is there a smart way to solve this?

---

This problem is coming from a physics problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tfrac{2}{50}<\tfrac{1}{20}$, so in $[0,2/50]$ your function is just
$$
8-\exp\left(-\frac{2500t}3\right),
$$
which is obviously increasing, so the maximum is at the right endpoint and its value is
$$
8-\exp\left(-\frac{100}3\right).
$$

---

Also, notice that your original function is discontinuous. I don't know if this is ok or by mistake. Probably by mistake...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On the discontinuous part of the function it is straight down, so I think that it is correct.